# Does a user need admin rights to install Flash player?

Tags: windows, linux, flash, macos, unix

Will users who do not have admin rights on their computers be able to upgrade to new Flash player version by themselves?

This would be interesting to know for:
Windows 98
Windows XP/2000/Vista
Macs
Unix/Linux

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [the Adobe instructions](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/productinfo/instructions/) for more clarification...

I know on Linux, at least, you do not need admin privs. Flash is installed in `~/.mozilla/plugins` when you use the `.tar.gz`ed installer script.

On Windows, I *think* there's only the option of doing a system-wide install so you need Administrator rights.

From the instructions for both Mac and Windows:

> Installation of Adobe Flash Player may require administrative access to your PC, which is normally provided by your IT department.

*May* require? Thanks for being clear, Adobe =) I think it's safe to assume they do as they're both system-integrated installers. The same goes for Linux if you use the YUM/RPM installers. If you use the script, you can run it as anybody with execution rights.

Answer (score 5):

For Mac the answer is "not really, but then again, yes" :P

Actually he wouldn't need it. On Mac there is a directory for browser plugins. No matter if you use Safari or Firefox (or possibly another browser), it is standard or Mac that browsers search their plugins in that folder. It is named:

```
Library/Internet Plug-ins
```

And as always on Mac, this directory exists twice. Once as system directory

```
/Library/Internet Plug-ins
```

and also once for every user

```
/Users/<username>/Library/Internet Plug-ins
```

It doesn't matter into which directory a user puts a plugin, the browser will look into both. That means if I put it into the System's Library folder, all users will have the plugin, if I put it into my folder only, only my user has it.

So far the theory. The problem in practice is that Adobe doesn't ship the flash plugin as a plugin file, you could just copy into either location (why not? On Mac almost any app or plugin could just be shipped as a file. It really won't kill the user to manually copy it somewhere), but it ships an installer (I **hate** installers on Mac). And the installer wants to put it into the System's Library folder for all users AFAIK. To do that, it will prompt the user for the appropriate permissions and only an admin user can grant these permissions.

Answer (score 4):

**For Windows:** yes you need admin rights for the system to install flash player. which installs through an exe file

Answer (score 3):

I just managed to get it working for a Mac OS X without admin rights.

Download the installer from Adobe and make sure to save it somewhere, rather than letting it automatically open.  Unzip the installation archive and you should end up with "Install Flash Player 10" mounted.  Check inside that, but instead of opening "Adobe Flash Player.pkg", right click that file to Show Package Contents.

In the folder that pops up, open Contents and look for archive.pax.gz or resources/adobe flash player.pax.gz, both seem to contain the same things.  Unzip that archive.

You'll find flashplayer.xpt and flash player.plugin in there.  Copy both of them to users/whichever user you are/library/internet plugins... if you see those files there already, it's the right place, just want to replace them with the new ones, then restart your browser.

Hopefully that'll work for you.

Answer (score 2):

**NO** If your using Firefox 
Download the XPI archive of the Flash Player Plugin to your hard drive
http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/xpi/current/flashplayer-win.xpi

Rename the file you downloaded, called flashplayer-win.xpi, into flashplayer-win.zip 
Extract the files in the archive

## Copy the files flashplayer.xpt and NPSWF32.dll to %APPDATA%\Mozilla\Plugins\

```
* %APPDATA% is the folder which holds your applications profiles and settings.
* You can open this folder simply choosing "Start → Run → Type in %APPDATA% → OK".
```

## Restart Firefox